# Jquery use after load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm failing to use jquery functions after I'm using partials - .load() function.
I've tried functions like .val() and background-image change, and nothing happens.
I guess it has something with the .load() because I cant find any other reason...
Maybe I have to use live func or something...
Thats my main div at home page which I load inside it when I'm navigatin at my site:

```
<div id="mainContent">
</div>
```

Thats the other page which I load into the mainContent :

```
<div id="carNavigation" onload="rentPics()">
<div class="carDivs" id="d1"></div>
<div class="carDivs" id="d2"></div>
<br>
<div class="carDivs" id="d3"></div>
<div class="carDivs" id="d4"></div>
<div class="carHeads" id="mazHead">Mazda</div>
<div class="carHeads" id="toyHead">Toyota</div>
<div class="carHeads" id="porHead">Porsche</div>
<div class="carHeads" id="infHead">Infinity</div>
</div>
```

And thats my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mainContent').css('background-image', 'url(wood.jpg)');
   });

function loadPage(str)
{
    if (str=="Aboutus")
    {
        $('#mainContent').load('aboutus.html');
        $('#mainContent').css('background-image', 'url(familycar.png)');
    }
    if (str=="rentcar")
    {
        $('#mainContent').load('rentCar.html');
        $('#mainContent').css('background-image', 'url(wood.jpg)');
    }
    if (str=="registration")
    {
        $('#mainContent').load('registration.html');
    }
}
function rentPics()
{
    $('#d1').css('background-image','url(familycar.png)');
}
```

CSS Code:

```
/* Rent Car Page Css*/
.carDivs
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border-radius: 65px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 15px #FFFFFF;
}
#d1 ,#d2
{
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 155px;
    margin-top: -120px;
}

#d3, #d4
{
    margin-top: 112px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 155px;
}

#mazHead
{
    margin-left: 235px;
}
#toyHead
{
    margin-left: 683px;
    margin-top: -26px;
}
#porHead
{
    margin-top: 269px;
    margin-right: 87px;
    margin-left: 217px;
}
#infHead
{
    margin-top: 268px;
    margin-left: 260px;
}

.carHeads
{
    display:inline-block;
    font-family: Copperplate, "Copperplate Gothic Light", fantasy;
    font-size: 26px;
    vertical-align:top
}
```

Comment: please post full code including the css.

Comment: Use "onload" attribute on body tag...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call `rentPics()` after your 'page' has loaded into the DOM.

Something like that:

```
$.load("url_to_your_page_containing_carNavigation", function () {
   renderPics();
});
```

The second argument (the function...) will be called only when the page has finished loading, and thus, when `#d1` will be available in the DOM tree.

See official `$.load` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for further details.

Comment: Just worked, cant give you a positive one since I'm rookie but hope the others will:)